# How can I cite from different bib file respectively?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, multibib

[image][image]Because I am answering questions and each question I want to cite different references, so I need to use different bib files, and when I cite in different questions, it will strat from 1. For example, if I want cite this sentence\cite{1}, where 1 is from 1.bib. And in the same tex file, I want to cite this new sentence\cite{2}, where 2 is from 2.bib. And this should be like this: I want to cite this sentence[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCPeG.png); I want to cite this new sentence[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCPeG.png), and finally I can have references for each bib file.

I found a way to solve this, but need to write ref manually.

Comment: are you using biblatex as the tag you used suggests?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the example you give, both works come out as "[1]" in the citation. Is that really what you want? How can your readers tell the two different sources apart? Can you explain your current setup and what exactly you want to achieve in more detail, please?

Comment: Thanks for  Answering! I don't expect to get a comment so fast and sorry for vague question. I will make it more clear